# Can I deny access to a Wordpress directory with MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a directory in my website called /MyFiction. It is an installed version of Wordpress for a particular blog and I would like to keep it to where you can only get to it if you're authenticated. I'm an old hat to ASP.NET but with MVC I'm still a newbie....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the directory up in your web.config the way you would with standard ASP.NET, but make sure to ignore the route in your MVC web site via Application_Start.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("/MyFiction/{*pathInfo}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still use the [`<location>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7.aspx) element in your `web.config` to restrict access to certain folders.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm right here, but have you tried dropping a web.Config file in the directory with permissions content?

> @tvanfosson said it right.  Standard Web Forms authentication is still valid as long as you remove the directory from your Routes.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to add

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("/MyFiction/{*pathInfo}");
```

because in MVC by default the setting `routes.RouteExistingFiles` is set to false so you can just drop web.config in the root folder that will deny access to all users

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
      </system.web>
.....
```